# Run-time error when using the 'Run' method of the 'WScript.Shell' object

Tags: vba, excel, cmd, excel-2010

I'm trying to run a command prompt via VBA to execute a couple of commands, but I have run in to an error.

> Run-time error '-214702894(80070002)':
>   Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed

I have tried wrapping file paths in quotes (as below), but the error persists which ever method I use.

```
Shell.Run "cd """ & MyDocumentsPath & """", 1, True
Shell.Run "cd " & Chr(34) & MyDocumentsPath & "Chr(34)", 1, True
```

I also tried to directly type a file path (with no spaces), but that failed too.

```
Shell.Run "cd ""C:\Users\GardD""", 1, True
```

Is anybody able to spot any issues? Here is my full code -

```
Dim Shell As Object ' An instance of the 'Shell' object
Set Shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim MyDocumentsPath As String   ' The path to the current users 'My Documents' folder
MyDocumentsPath = GetMyDocumentsPath

Shell.Run "cd " & MyDocumentsPath, 1, True  ' Change the Shell start location to the users 'My Documents' folder
Shell.Run DIR_CMD & DIR_FILE_PATH, 1, True  ' Output the full file paths of all files in the users 'My Documents' folder

Set Shell = Nothing ' Destroy the 'Shell' object
```

Comment: Are you aware that VBA has `ChDir Statement`?

Comment: I was, but the second part of my requirement is to output a list of all files in the users My Documnets folder to a text file.  I can do this via `cmd` using the `dir` command, but I'm unaware of a similarly fast/reliable method of doing that through Excel, hence my use of the `Shell` object.  I'm always open to suggestions if I'm missing somthing though...

Comment: Fast? Maybe not. Reliable? Definitely. `DIR` in VBA is pretty reliable

Comment: Well it may be fast if you want to get the entire directory tree in a text file. Imagine if there is a folder with 1000 subfolders and all folders have files in it. A simple recursive DIR can give you all the file listing in a text file. Imagine using cmd statements to achieve all that :D There are lot of sample codes in stackoverflow which show you how to use DIR recursive ly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not an executable; its a command that only exists within a (cmd.exe) console session, ditto for `dir` if that's what's in `DIR_CMD`.

You could `Shell.Run "cmd /c cd c:\temp & dir *.xls", 1, true`

Probably better to use VBA to do whatever you want to do at the command line.

Comment: Ok, I see the logic now. I'm still struggling slighlty though as I need to run two successive commands - 1. "cd C:\Users\GardD\Documents" (the path will change based on the user, but I can handle that) and 2. "dir *.* /s /b  >c:\dir.txt" (I use constants to store those values so that I can easily change them).  How can I run those two commands one after the other, as the second relies on the "cd" action carried out by the first.

Comment: My example does that, use the `command1 & command2` syntax - to repeat VBA can do this natively!

Comment: Agree with Alex on this one! Why not use VBA's inbuilt commands?

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Sorry, I misread your answer, but you are quite right and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could actually build a single command: `dir "C:\Users\GardD\Documents" /s /b >c:\dir.txt`

Comment: Also on recent versions of windows write access to the root of C: will be denied

Comment: Good point. All of the users who will use this ***should*** be administrators, but, I'll probably change the location just in case...